# Using a Shell Script to Connect to a Postgres (Redshift) database and table

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, amazon-redshift

I need help understanding some pieces of a shell script to connect to a Redshift database because Bash/shell is unfamiliar for me.

1. to use `pgpass`, is this all I need to get the credentials? :

   ```
   cat > ./.pgpass <<-CREDS
   $HOSTNAME:$PORT_NUMBER:$DBNAME:$USERNAME:$PASSWORD
   CREDS
   ```
2. What is `<<-`? Is it a comment? Quick search says that `<<END` is a comment but is that anything different from `<<-CREDS`?
3. This is somewhat related to #2, what do `<<-ATOMIC` and `\x` mean in this snippet?

   ```
   $PSQL_CMD <<-ATOMIC
   \x
   SELECT column1 FROM $THETABLE WHERE column1='true';
   ATOMIC
   ```

Since `ATOMIC` is at the end of this block, I would presume that it's stating the end of a block or something, but I don't understand the documentation or anything.

4. How do I assign the returned value(s) of the `SELECT` statement into a variable and echo it into an email? I have a line to send the email, but don't know how to assign the returned values from the `SELECT` query into a variable:

   ```
   $ echo "hello world" | mail -s "Test" simply@coding.com
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. To my knowledge, `pgpass` won't contain your credentials unless you've put them in there yourself.  This sounds like maybe command to do that.
2. `<<-` is not a comment. It represents a 'Here document'  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix-Shells
3. Regarding `<<-ATOMIC` see the above link.  The `\x` tells psql to format the output from your `SELECT`
4. ```
   OUTPUT = `psql -U username -h host -d dbname tablename -c $PSQL_CMD'
   echo $OUTPUT | mail -s "Test" simply@coding.com
   ```